# How to get the current pages Page Design in code

Tags: sxa

In code, how can I access the current `Page Design` my Page is using?

Tried to find something in the `RenderingReference` no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite simple, you need to use `PresentationContext` service. Here is an example:

```
ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPresentationContext>().GetDesignItem(CONTEXT_ITEM);
```

It will do all the work your you:

1. check if there is design selected on your page
2. check design rules
3. and at the end check Template to Design Mapping field (if design won't be resolved from above ones)

You can also inject `PresentationContext` using constructor injection like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected readonly IPresentationContext PresentationContext;

    public MyClass(IPresentationContext presentationContext)
    {
        PresentationContext = presentationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. Is this somewhere documented? These GetService() is new for me, I have seen in the showconfig.aspx that there are a lot more of these ServiceTypes, just wondering what each of them is able to provide.